# Plotting 3D graphs of quadric surfaces

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot, pst-3dplot

I have trouble plotting these 3D graphs of Quadric surfaces. If anybody could help or direct me to a link where I can find codes for corresponding graphs, it would be really helpful.

Hyperbolic paraboloid
[image]

Elliptical Cone
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16,trig format plots=rad,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix{
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
  \addplot3[domain=-5:5,domain y=-5:5,surf,z
  buffer=sort,shader=interp,opacity=0.5] 
  (x*x-y*y,x,y);
 \end{axis}\\
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
  \addplot3[domain=-3:3,domain y=0:2*pi,surf,z
  buffer=sort,shader=interp,opacity=0.5] 
  (x,{x*cos(y)},{x*sin(y)});
 \end{axis}\\
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
  \addplot3[domain=-3:-1,domain y=0:2*pi,surf,z
  buffer=sort,shader=interp,opacity=0.5] 
  (x,{sqrt(x*x-1)*cos(y)},{sqrt(x*x-1)*sin(y)});
  \addplot3[domain=1:3,domain y=0:2*pi,surf,z
  buffer=sort,shader=interp,opacity=0.5] 
  (x,{sqrt(x*x-1)*cos(y)},{sqrt(x*x-1)*sin(y)});
 \end{axis}\\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16,}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/x axis/.style={code={\draw 
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0,0) -- 
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0,0);}},
    pics/y axis/.style={code={\draw 
    (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin},0) -- 
        (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},0);}},
  /pgfplots/.cd,trig format plots=rad,hide axis,colormap/viridis]
 \matrix{
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot3[domain=-5:5,domain y=-5:0,surf,z
   buffer=sort,shader=interp]   (x*x-y*y,x,y);
  \path pic{x axis} pic{y axis};
  \addplot3[domain=-5:5,domain y=0:5,surf,z
   buffer=sort,shader=interp]   (x*x-y*y,x,y);
  \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,25); 
 \end{axis}\\
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot3[domain=-3:3,domain y=pi:2*pi,surf,z
   buffer=sort,shader=interp] 
   (x,{x*cos(y)},{x*sign(x)*sin(y)});
  \path pic{x axis} pic{y axis};
  \addplot3[domain=-3:3,domain y=0:pi,surf,z
   buffer=sort,shader=interp] 
   (x,{x*cos(y)},{x*sign(x)*sin(y)});
  \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);  
 \end{axis}\\
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot3[domain=-3:-1,domain y=pi:2*pi,surf,z
    buffer=sort,shader=interp] 
    (x,{sqrt(x*x-1)*cos(y)},{sqrt(x*x-1)*sin(y)});
  \addplot3[domain=1:3,domain y=pi:2*pi,surf,z
    buffer=sort,shader=interp] 
   (x,{sqrt(x*x-1)*cos(y)},{sqrt(x*x-1)*sin(y)});
  \path pic{x axis} pic{y axis};
  \addplot3[domain=-3:-1,domain y=0:pi,surf,z
    buffer=sort,shader=interp] 
    (x,{sqrt(x*x-1)*cos(y)},{sqrt(x*x-1)*sin(y)});
  \addplot3[domain=1:3,domain y=0:pi,surf,z
    buffer=sort,shader=interp] 
   (x,{sqrt(x*x-1)*cos(y)},{sqrt(x*x-1)*sin(y)});
  \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,{sqrt(8)}); 
 \end{axis}\\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me what needs to be done if I need to rotate the cone?. For ex: If I need to make the cone symmetric about Z-axis (instead of X-axis), what needs to be added to the existing code?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy I am not really online now and plan to add an example later. One way to achieve this is to swap the first and last components of the vectors after \addplot3 ...

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat   Thanks.That worked!!